# Documentation window blank in Android Studio

Tags: android, ide

Android studio shows blank documentation window like this. Is there any solution to get documentation. I am suffering from this problem after updating the android studio to latest version 1.0.1 Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you resize the window by dragging down on the bottom part of the bar?

Comment: Thank you. I had collapsed the window by mistake.

Comment: I had a new install and collapsed seems to be the default. I thought I always had to press Ctrl+Q twice!

Comment: This does not seem to work. The window collapses again after a while.